# Eager load Paperclip's has_attached_file data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, eager-loading

`Product has_many :assets`

`Asset belongs_to :product`

`Asset has_attached_file :photo` using Paperclip (with all your standard Paperclip options; a few styles, S3 storage).

If I form a Product query like `p = Product.includes(:assets)` I can call each of the actual attributes of Asset without incurring any additional database queries, like:

```
p = Product.includes(:assets)
p.each { |a| print a.assets.first.title }
```

The `title` attribute on `Asset` (which is a database column) prints, no queries made.

To get the URL generated by Paperclip:

```
p = Product.includes(:assets)
p.each { |a| print a.assets.first.photo.url }
```

causes a separate additional query for each `Product`:

```
Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
```

According to [this G.Groups posting](http://groups.google.com/group/paperclip-plugin/browse_thread/thread/daa6fb6d4b44f1d2), I shouldn't be hitting the database with each pass through the loop, but I am.

Is there a way to not incur the additional database hit for each iteration, but gather all the data all at once? Am I overlooking something simple?

Rails 3.0.9, REE 1.8.7, Paperclip 2.3.11.

**updated, fixed**

The issue is that in my Paperclip settings, I have `:product_id` as part of the `:path`: `:attachment/:product_id/:filename-:style.:extension`, which is causing the additional Product query for each iteration through the loop.

By changing the query to `p = Product.includes(:assets => [:product]).all`, it removed the additional query.

Comment: I tested your scenario on my machine and everything worked as expected. Can you post a pastie link to the actual errant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get to the root of the problem much faster if you use one of the query analyzer plugins Try query-reviewer, or if you're using newrelic, the dev mode includes this. You'll get a stack trace for every query. I don't think it has anything to do with eager loading - if it did, you'd be getting extra Asset loads instead of Product loads.

Comment: I installed query-reviewer but every page showed zero queries, even though I can see them all firing in the log. I'll double-check my install and try again.

Comment: Even though this doesn't solve the problem, your comment about it not being about eager loading due to it not being Asset loads put me on the right path to figuring it out myself, so I'm awarding you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overlooking something simple:

```
p = Product.includes(:assets).all
```

`includes` sets the relation to eager load the association, `all` does the actual query.

```
irb(main):001:0> p = Product.includes(:assets)
=> ..........
irb(main):002:0> p.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
irb(main):003:0> p.all.class
=> Array
```

Comment: I don't believe in Rails 3+ that the `.all` is necessary, it's the default. Looking at my logs, `Product.includes(:assets)` gives me `SELECT "products" . * FROM "products"` for the first query, `SELECT "assets" . * from "assets" WHERE ("assets".product_Id IN (...big list...)`

Comment: The `includes` call returns a relation, it doesn't actually do a query. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/235a4142aa3fee73faa0f01e267a2b4254cea8ce/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L12). It's not a finder method like `all` is. Try adding it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my issue. I still get an additional query `Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = # LIMIT 1` for each Product found from the query when I run `p.each { |a| print a.assets.first.photo.url }`, whether I include `.all` or not.

Comment: Do you get an initial query that loads all of the products?

Comment: Yes, log shows `Product Load (61.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  Asset Load (78.5ms)  SELECT "assets".* FROM "assets" WHERE ("assets".product_id IN (all the matching product_ids)`. I show the same as you in irb; `Product.includes(:assets)` is an AR::Relation, `Product.includes(:assets).all` is an Array.

Comment: And you're sure `p` is an Array before you start iterating over it? Sorry to keep asking the same thing, but this isn't making a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Definitely. `p = Product.includes(:assets).all` gives me two queries (one for Product, one for Assets with product_ids). `p.class` is Array. Then, `p.each {|a| print a.assets.first.photo.url }` causes a `Product Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1` query, where the `"products"."id" = 1` increments by product id.

Comment: Huh. I'm running out of ideas. Try `p = Product.find(:all, :include => :assets)`. I think that's the right syntax.

Comment: Same result from using older syntax. Thanks for your effort though, I appreciate it.